# On Not-Safe-For-Work images

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, images

This is just an FYI to avoid the appearance of censorship. I am happy to hear feedback if you think I handled this incorrectly.

Recently, a question was asked about [diseased scrotums](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/worlds-largest-scrotum).

The question included a link to a YouTube video featuring scrotums. The accepted answer included an image of a diseased scrotum.

In my opinion, both the question and the answer were appropriate topics of investigation. I do not believe that we should avoid or censor such questions. However, I am sensitive to the fact that some people may be reading this site in a work environment, or may find such images disturbing.

I think that images that are sensitive and/or not safe for work should be hidden behind links with appropriate warnings, as a pragmatic solution. (Clearly, these images should be related to legitimate questions.)

Therefore, I attempted to make two changes:

- I added a note to the YouTube link explaining it may be disturbing and not safe for work.
- I attempted to remove the photo, and replace it with a link to the photo, with a similar warning on the link.

I trust neither of these changes is perceived as censorship. I didn't want to stop others looking at the subject, just prevent them from being accidentally displayed.

In the case of the photo, there was no attribution in the answer to the source of the photo. I couldn't simply link to the original source. I noted that in the comment and removed the image.

To be clear, I wanted to replace the image with a link because it was not safe for work.
But, I removed the link because I did not know the original source. I would be happy to return a link if the answerer can provide the appropriate source.

Comment: You might try using tineye.com to find if a legitimate site uses the same image and gives credit.

Comment: I was hoping the original poster could explain where he got the image from. If not, then yes, Tin Eye can be useful for that.

Comment: And in fact I think you could perfectly link to the uploaded picture.

Comment: @johanvdw: I agree in principle. In this particular case, there was no attribution to the original source, and no obvious claim of "fair use", so I believe the uploaded copy to be infringing copyright. IANAL, I am just someone trying to respect the photographer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholder answer to get this question off the unanswered list